# Hibernate foreign key becomes null

Tags: hibernate, null, foreign-keys

I am using one to one mapping in hibernate I have two entities `RegisterPartner` and other is `Userdetails.userdetails` is having `user_id` as primary key and it is being used as foreign key in `RegisterPartner`  but when I save the entity it saves correctly except foreign key becomes `null`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_login")
 public class Userdetails implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="user_id")
private int user_id;
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userdetail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
private RegisterPartner registerpartner ;


public Userdetails(){

}
}   

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_partner")
public class RegisterPartner implements  Serializable , Comparable<RegisterPartner>{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="register_id")
private int register_id;

@Column(name="agency_name")
private String agencyname;

@Column(name="agency_type")
private int agencytype;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
private Userdetails userdetail;

public RegisterPartner(){}

 }
```

### save code

```
 public String savePartnerRegister(){

    RegisterPartner registerpartner = new RegisterPartner();  
    Userdetails userdetails = new Userdetails();
    registerpartner.setAgencyname(getAgencyname());
    registerpartner.setAgencytype(getAgencytype());

    userdetails.setUsername(getUsername());
    userdetails.setPassword(getPassword());

    userdetails.setRegisterpartner(registerpartner);
    registerpartner.setUserdetail(userdetails);

     SessionFactory sessionFactory= HibernateManager.getSessionFactory();
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(userdetails);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close()

}
```

not understanding what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, which is used to say that the primary key is also a foreign key. You should use `@JoinColumn`.